# Remove QGIS Project from Geopackage

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I recently accidentally saved a QGIS Project to the wrong Geopackage. In contrast to layers the Browser Panel in QGIS (Version 3.10) currently has no option in the context menu to remove the project again:

[image: Option to Delete a layer]

[image]

Does anybody have a python code or another workaround to remove the Project from the Geopackage in QGIS 3.10?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The option to remove a project from a GeoPackage is simple, if a bit counter-intuitive.

1. Go to **Project** > **Save To** > **GeoPackage...**
2. On the dialog that appears, choose the appropriate connection and project.
3. Click **Manage Projects** > **Remove Project**
4. The program will prompt you to confirm removal. Click **Yes**.

And that should do it! You can just cancel out of the **Save to** dialog now.

[image: manage projects]